# Error loading data from CSV into tensorflow model using tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset()

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am attempting to input data from a CSV into a TensorFlow object using the `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset` function. I am recieving the following error:

```
raise ValueError("No files match %s." % file_pattern)
ValueError: No files match    Subject    BDV  Classification
0     6040 -18.26               0
1     6160 -20.95               0
2    6140D -17.46               0
3     5973 -16.92               1
4     5986 -16.52               1
5     6040 -16.43               1
6    5970C -13.79               2
7     6041 -12.25               2
8     5969 -12.81               2
9     6030 -13.85               2
10   6041B -15.07               2
11    6082 -12.49               2
12   6082C -13.89               2
13    6088 -13.49               2
14    6110 -14.17               2
15    6041 -12.12               2
16    6067 -13.61               2
17    6077 -15.21               2
18    6089 -13.46               2
19   61052 -13.87               2
20   6092A -15.64               2
21    6089 -14.07               2
22    6061 -13.74               2
23    6073 -13.66               2
24    6089 -14.60               2
25    6050 -13.28               2
26    6059 -14.10               2
27   6073A -13.47               2
28    6081 -13.77               2
29   6118E -12.24               2
30   6121A -13.74               2
31   5977B -14.50               2
32   5935A -13.81               2
33    6010 -13.30               2
34   6009B -13.32               2
35   6009A -13.02               2
36   5992A -13.58               2
37   5948B -14.68               2.
```

I am following a similar structure to the tensorflow iris classifier example that they give on the website, except the CSV is locally stored on my computer.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import requests

#Print version of tensorflow on current machine || should be 2.0
print("TensorFlow version: {}".format(tf.__version__))
print("Eager execution: {}".format(tf.executing_eagerly()))

train_dataset_fp = pd.read_csv('bdv.csv')

print("Local copy of the dataset file: {}".format(train_dataset_fp))

column_names = ['Subject', 'BDV', 'Classification']

feature_names = column_names[:-1]
label_name = column_names[-1]
# prints the features of the dataset. Label 0: Iris setosa; Label 1: versicolor; Label 2: virginica
print("Features: {}".format(feature_names))
print("Label: {}".format(label_name))

class_names = ['Class1', 'Class2', 'Class3']

batch_size = 32

train_dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(train_dataset_fp,
                                                      batch_size,
                                                      column_names=column_names,
                                                      label_name=label_name,
                                                      num_epochs=1)


features, labels = next(iter(train_dataset))
print(features)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: if you get error in `make_csv_dataset()` then use `print()` and `print(type(...))` to see values in variables which you use in `make_csv_dataset()` - and check in documentation if you use correct data in these variables. Maybe you use dataframe but it expects filename.

Comment: see doc for [make_csv_dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/make_csv_dataset) it seems first argument has to be list of filenames or strings like `folder/*.csv` but you use strange data from file `'bdv.csv'`. Maybe you need `.make_csv_dataset(['bdv.csv'], ...`

Answer (score 0):

You need filename `'bdv.csv'` as first argument in `make_csv_dataset()`

```
train_dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset( 'bdv.csv', ... )
```

or list of filenames

```
train_dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset( ['bdv.csv'], ... )
```

or pattern for `glob` - single `'*.csv'` or list `['folder1/*.csv', 'folder2/*.csv', '2020*.csv']`

---

Doc: [make_csv_dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/make_csv_dataset)

---

**BTW:** Error shows that you use CSV with multi spaces as separator. In `read_csv()` you could use regex `sep='\s+'` to read it correctly but `make_csv_dataset` can use ony single char `field_delim=' '` and it can make problem to read it. You may have to use `read_csv()` and `to_csv()` to fix this file